# Help pages don't exist on new MoinMoin installation?

Tags: apache-2.2, installation, wiki, moinmoin

I installed MoinMoin on Ubuntu 11.04 using the instructions in
http://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuQuick, including the (first two) bullets
for Ubuntu 10.10 in [the Suggestions section at the bottom](http://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuQuick#Suggestions).

Apache and MoinMoin are running on a machine at my employer with the
hostname "daryls".  (Only visible behind the firewall, of course.)  So
http://daryls/ goes to MyStartingPage.

When I click on HelpOnEditing and HelpOnMoinWikiSyntax while editing a
page, I get a blank page.  HelpContents (when I click on the
HelpContents tab) is also blank.

I found [a question in MoinMoin's documentation](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinQuestions#MoinMoinQuestions.2BAC8-Errors.reference_to_mywiki_for_HelpOnEditing_.2BAC8_SyntaxReference) where a similar problem to mine is described.  But clicking on
HelpOnEditing goes to http://daryls/HelpOnEditing,
HelpOnMoinWikiSyntax to http://daryls/HelpOnMoinWikiSyntax and
HelpContents goes to http://daryls/HelpContents.  (I don't have the
extra "/instance_name/" in the URL as they describe.)  But just to be
sure, I cleared the contents of /usr/share/moin/data/cache, which made
no difference.

I too wonder (like "twm" in [the question](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinQuestions#MoinMoinQuestions.2BAC8-Errors.reference_to_mywiki_for_HelpOnEditing_.2BAC8_SyntaxReference)) whether this is a
configuration error.  Do I need to tell MoinMoin or Apache that the
domain name of the server is "daryls"?

Comment: FYI I previously posted this same question to the moin-user mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTin_O9-td7n6u8KricEo4%3D%2BMSzjYjw%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=moin-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't follow the instructions in [section 3.3](http://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuQuick#Language_setup) of http://moinmo.in/HowTo/UbuntuQuick.  It all works now that I have installed "all_pages".